# Rijndael AES encryption algorithm doesn't work on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, encryption, java-me, aes, rijndael

I am using Rijndael AES encryption algorithm in my RhoMobile Development for
Android and BlackBerry.

It is working on Android, but for BlackBerry I can't get the exact encrypted text.

Comment: How about adding more details?

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? we are also searching for Rijndael implementation for BlackBerry, any help will be greatly appreciated. regards
Jeet